# Combinatorics problem on number of possible outcomes with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

*We have 12 fish and 6 types.
How many possible outcomes if at least 3 are of certain type.*

Ok, I reason as follows x1 + x2 + ... + x5 <= 9, and x6 >= 3 .
But, now I do not know what to do because these sums can very in the above constraints.
If it would be x1 + x2 + ... + x6 = 12 it is easy by applying formula 
*(n + r - 1) choose (r-1)*
I have no idea what approach to apply when result of x1 + x2 + ... + x5 sum can very based on x6, which is >= 3.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is trout a kind of fish? If yes, it's just $6^9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the number of integral solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_6=12$

with $x_i\ge0$ for $1\le i\le5$ and $x_6\ge3$.

If we let $y_i=x_i$ for $1\le i\le 5$ and $y_6=x_6-3$, this gives

$\;\;\;y_1+\cdots+y_6=9$ with $y_i\ge0$ for $1\le i\le6$, and there are $\dbinom{14}{5}$ solutions to this equation.

---

Another way we could work this is to take the total number of solutions, and subtract the number of possibilities for getting 0, 1, or 2  trout.

This would give $\displaystyle\binom{17}{5}-\binom{16}{4}-\binom{15}{4}-\binom{14}{4}$ possibilities.

Comment: can you explain why we have 16 choose 4 and then 15 choose 4 and then 14 choose 4? I do not understand why it is 4 ....

Comment: if you are specifically fixed on 0 trout, for example, then it's equivalent to the problem of 12 fish with 5 types, which is ${12 + 5 - 1 \choose 5 - 1}$, etc.

Comment: @Bridgeburners Thanks for explaining this.  (I had left for the evening before this question was asked.)

Answer (score 1):

Well it helps to think about *why* it's ${n+r-1 \choose r-1}$ in the unconstrained problem, and that would help us adjust for this constraint.

Consider the problem where you have 17 bins lined up left to right, and 5 walls to place, one in each bin. How many possible ways can you arrange the walls in the bins? ${17 \choose 5}$. How does that relate to the fish problem? Well, when you place the bins down, you have created 6 divisions (including end-to-wall divisions), with a total of 12 empty slots over all the divisions. Then, each division, with the number of empty slots you left, represents the number of fish you caught out of the 12. So, for example, if labelled the fish "fish 1, fish 2, fish 3, fish 4, fish 5, and trout" then the division between the very left end and the first wall represents the number of "fish 1" you caught, the division between wall 1 and wall 2 represents the number of "fish 2", etc... up to the division between wall 5 and the right end being the number of trout. And if, for example, the second wall is right beside the third wall, that means you caught zero of "fish 3", or if you place the fifth wall at the very end, you caught zero trout, etc.

Now with your constraint, of the 17 slots you cannot place a wall anywhere further than the 14th slot, because placing a wall any further than that means there's less than 3 trout. Thus you have 5 walls, and only 14 slots to choose from, and the analogy of divisions based on wall placement choices holds identically. Thus, your options for placing walls is limited down to ${14 \choose 5}$, and so is that the number of combinations of number of fish caught for each type, if at least three trout are caught.